# HOC - Type '{...}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropType'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, typescript-typings, react-hoc

Hi I'm getting this error :

```
Type '{ children: Element; onClickOutside: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PopUpWrapperProps'.
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PopUpWrapperProps'.ts(2322)
```

when trying to use `<PopUpWrapper>` in `InfoIcon.tsx`, I'm guessing it comes from a bad typing in `withPortal.tsx` but I tried many things and didn't get the error to disappear...
Do you have any idea on how to solve this ?

---

### Files :

withPortal.tsx

```
const withPortal = <P extends object>(Component : React.ComponentType<P>, querySelector = "#portal") => (props : P)  => {
    const isMounted = useMounted(null)
    return isMounted && ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <Component {...props}/>, 
        document.querySelector(querySelector)
    )
}

export default withPortal
```

PopUpWrapper.tsx

```
interface PopUpWrapperProps {
    onClickOutside: () => void
}

const PopUpWrapper : React.FC<PopUpWrapperProps> = ({children, onClickOutside}) => {

    ...

    return <div className={styles.popup_wrapper} ref={ref} onClick={handleClick}>
        {children}
    </div>
}

export default withPortal(PopUpWrapper)
```

InfoIcon.tsx

```
interface InfoIconProps {
    src: string,
    alt: string
    className?: string,
    isProtected?: boolean
}

const InfoIcon : React.FC<InfoIconProps> = ({
    src, alt, children, className = "", isProtected = true
}) => {

    ...

    return <div className={styles.info_icon}>
    
        ...
        
        {
            identity === Identity.Testing && 
            <PopUpWrapper onClickOutside={cancelIdendityTest}> //error here
                <IdentityPopup />
            </PopUpWrapper>
        }
    </div>
}

export default InfoIcon;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add children to your props type:

```
interface PopUpWrapperProps {
    onClickOutside: () => void,
    children: any
}
```

Comment: If you want to avoid any, you can specify the type of children as ReactNode, that is `children: ReactNode`,